# How to insert values with Foreign KEY in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys, content-values

I am new with Android **Sqlite Database**.
I have created a database with SQLite in Android and I have a table `Student_details` which use a foreign key of the table: `Student`, I have made the id as `AUTOINCREMENT`.
And i tried to **return** the value of the `AUTOINCREMENT` Id from `Student` table.

But I am stuck to use the `return values` to insert into `COLUMN_FR_KEY_USER_ID = "student_id";` as Foreign Key values.

How can I add value with a foreign key from another table using `ContentValues` into `insetDataIntoStudentDetails` method?

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "finalStudent.db";
    private static final int VERSION_NUMBER = 16;
    private static final String TABLE_STUDENT = "Student";
    private static final String TABLE_DETAILS_NAME = "Student_details";

    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_DETAILS_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_FR_KEY_USER_ID = "student_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_DETAILS_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String COLUMN_STUDENT_PASSWORD = "password";

    private static final String CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_STUDENT+"( "+COLUMN_STUDENT_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COLUMN_STUDENT_NAME+" TEXT, "+COLUMN_STUDENT_EMAIL+" TEXT, "+COLUMN_STUDENT_PASSWORD+" TEXT)";
    private static final String CREATE_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_DETAILS_NAME+"( "+COLUMN_DETAILS_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+COLUMN_DETAILS_NAME+" TEXT, "+COLUMN_FR_KEY_USER_ID+" INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY("+COLUMN_FR_KEY_USER_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_STUDENT+" ("+COLUMN_STUDENT_ID+") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)";

    private Context context;
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_STUDENT;
    private static final String DROP_DETAILS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_DETAILS_NAME;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, VERSION_NUMBER);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Table created successfully and called onCreate method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL(CREATE_STUDENT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DETAILS_TABLE);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception : "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Table created successfully and called onCreate method",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(DROP_DETAILS_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Exception : "+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    public long insertDataIntoStudent( String name, String email, String password){
        // to write or read data in database , we have to call getWritableDatabase
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // we have to call contentValues class to store data in the data

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_EMAIL,email);
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_STUDENT_PASSWORD,password);

        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_STUDENT,null,contentValues);
        return newRowId;
    }


    public void insetDataIntoStudentDetails(String name){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
       // TODO: insert the foreign key's value 
        contentValues.put(name,name);
    }


    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        //enable foreign key constraints like ON UPDATE CASCADE, ON DELETE CASCADE
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final AppCompatActivity activity = MainActivity.this;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(activity);
        databaseHelper.insertDataIntoStudent("Bappy","abcd@gmail.com","145456");
    }
    }
```

Comment: While I know this doesn't answer your question, you might want to evaluate using Room since you are using a database.

Comment: @Bink thanks for the kind suggestion, but i have no idea about ```room``` , I mean how it works or other staff of ```room```.

Comment: You can find more detail about the Room Persistence Library at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.

Comment: @Bink well, i got some understanding tutorial about ```Room```. It's really amazing and easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer about databases in general, not specifically about Sqlite or it's usage in Android.

So you have student's name (which is not a primary key), but you need to save some additional data for this student to another table. The steps are:

1. Execute `SELECT id FROM students WHERE name = ?` to find the relevant identifier.
2. Execute `INSERT INTO student_details` for your secondary table using retrieved `id` as a key.

Extra tips:

1. Name is not a good unique identifier. It's good to have one more criteria - such as some group name, or group number or even date of birth.
2. When your database is large enough you may benefit from `index` for your search criteria to optimize execution of the first query. But usually it's not the case for client-side (in-app) databases.
3. Here we assume that name is not the data which could be updated by someone (or something) else between searching for `id` and executing `INSERT`. Otherwise it's wise to use transaction and "lock" your student until you complete the updates.

Comment: Thanks, i am new in that area, it will help me if i get specifically about ```Sqlite``` in Android.